# "A Cubic Function From the Reals to the Reals is Always Injective": False?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, polynomials, cubics

I heard an instructor say during a lecture that "a cubic function from the reals to the reals is always injective", but this is false, is it not? A cubic function is always surjective but not necessarily injective?

I just want to make sure before I point out the error.

Comment: you are correct.  $p(x)=x(x-1)(x+1)$ is a good counterexample.

Comment: I assume that $x\mapsto x^3-x$ is considered a cubic function by you instructor?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Yes. This was actually one of the examples I was just looking at, funnily enough.

Comment: Are you sure they didn't say "*the* cubic function from the reals to the reals is injective"? Or possibly they meant "a cubic function from the reals to the reals always has a root", but mispoke badly.

Comment: @PaulSinclair I confirmed with the instructor that they actually meant surjective, not injective, so they just misspoke.